# Работа потоков с Queue в java

Tags: java, многопоточность, очередь

У меня один поток кладет данные в очередь, другой забирает. Реализованы потоки в разных классах, и вызываются разными методами и тоже в разных классах. Как мне сделать для них общую очередь? А не создавался каждый раз новый объект при вызове.

Comment: Создайте очередь и передайте её в соответствующие классы при создании. Т.к. доступ будет многопоточным, то используйте ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Comment: Мне кажется в данном случае лучше использовать BlockingQueue, потому как BlockingDeque умеет ждать, пока в очередь что-то положат.